# Locked Column extjs 4.1

Tags: extjs4.1

I am trying to put grid in extjs 4.1 with locking feature
See the code below .

When defining column with locked feature

```
 var column = {"text":"Company","sortable":true,**locked:true**,"dataIndex":"company","width":350,"filterable":false};
```

I received following error

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'internalId' of undefined**

Here is html code :

```
<body> 

<div id ="divGrid"></div>
<script src="http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.0-gpl/ext-all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

Ext.require(['Ext.grid.*', 'Ext.data.*', 'Ext.util.*', 'Ext.state.*']);

Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL = 'Images/s.gif';
Ext.onReady(function () {

Ext.Loader.setConfig({ enabled: true });


    var data = {
            gridData: 
            [{ "company": "3m Co", "price": 71.72, "change": 0.02, "pctChange": 0.03, "lastChange": "2012-04-11T21:41:43.105Z" }, { "company": "Alcoa Inc", "price": 29.01, "change": 0.42, "pctChange": 1.47, "lastChange": "2012-04-11T21:41:43.105Z" }, { "company": "Altria Group Inc", "price": 83.81, "change": 0.28, "pctChange": 0.34, "lastChange": "2012-04-11T21:41:43.105Z" }, { "company": "American Express Company", "price": 52.55, "change": 0.01, "pctChange": 0.02, "lastChange": "2012-04-11T21:41:43.105Z" }, { "company": "American International Group, Inc.", "price": 64.13, "change": 0.31, "pctChange": 0.49, "lastChange": "2012-04-11T21:41:43.105Z" }, { "company": "AT&T Inc.", "price": 31.61, "change": -0.48, "pctChange": -1.54, "lastChange": "2012-04-11T21:41:43.105Z" }, { "company": "Boeing Co.", "price": 75.43, "change": 0.53, "pctChange": 0.71, "lastChange": "2012-04-11T21:41:43.105Z" }, { "company": "Caterpillar Inc.", "price": 67.27, "change": 0.92, "pctChange": 1.39, "lastChange": "2012-04-11T21:41:43.105Z" }, { "company": "Citigroup, Inc.", "price": 49.37, "change": 0.02, "pctChange": 0.04, "lastChange": "2012-04-11T21:41:43.105Z" }, { "company": "E.I. du Pont de Nemours and Company", "price": 40.48, "change": 0.51, "pctChange": 1.28, "lastChange": "2012-04-11T21:41:43.105Z"}]

    };

      var columns = [];
      var column = 
                        {"text":"Company","sortable":true,"dataIndex":"company","width":350,"filterable":false,locked:true}
                    ;

        columns.push(column);


        var fields = [];
        fields.push({ name: "company" });

       var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        autoLoad: true,
        fields: fields,
        data : data,
        proxy: {
            type: 'memory',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'gridData'
            }
        }
    });

        grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            store: store,
            selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.RowModel', { singleSelect: true, selectFirstRow: true }),
            columnLines: true,
            layout: 'fit', 
            renderTo:"divGrid",
            columns: columns,
            loadMask: false,
            height: 500,
            width: 500,
            dockedItems: [{
                xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
                store: store,
                dock: 'bottom',
                displayInfo: true
            }],
            viewConfig: {
                loadMask: false,
                id: "grid",
                stripeRows: true
            }
        });


    });
 </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in "id" field. I removed it and it's worked.

```
 viewConfig: {
                loadMask: false,
             //   **id: "grid",**
                stripeRows: true
            }
```